# select_for_update not seeming to work on Django 1.5.1 with MySql

Tags: mysql, django

I cannot for the life of me get select_for_update to work.

Here's my simplified code in my views.py file.

```
@transaction.commit_on_success
def Test(requet):
    start_time = time.time()
    liveOs = LiveOs.objects.select_for_update().get(serial_number="2B4E0AD08DD752FY6090")
    time_waiting_for_lock = time.time() - start_time
    time.sleep(10)
    return HttpResponse(time_waiting_for_lock*1000)
```

I call this from two browsers.  And each one returns after ~10s with a value of 1-2ms.  In other words, the 2nd HTTP query doesn't get blocked.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the `@transaction.atomic` decorator? Or you are using an older version of Django?

Comment: I'm using an older version of django- 1.5.1..  Also note the MySQL table is InnoDB so this should work.

Comment: Try a `nowait=True` argument. Does the second query raise a `DatabaseError`?

Comment: MySQL doesn't support nowait- https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/&ved=0ahUKEwiTuauympvKAhUH1B4KHTHEC90QFggZMAA&usg=AFQjCNGY_kvC6uLiymIziDEso_swyZ3jYQ&sig2=1-A28MtOZRoYiGPEKPhyrA

Comment: Your simplified code looks ok. Can you show the actual code?

Comment: Just guessing: if you change the `get()` call to a `filter()`, does anything change? Can you log the actual DB queries? @Alasdair is right, the code looks perfectly good.